# ZConfig.SchemaResourceError: could not load package ZServer: No module named interfaces

Tags: plone-3.x

iam using Plone4.3, i was working with the Plone themes.i changed the theme and restarted the Plonectl but suddenly i got this error

```
>  ZConfig.SchemaResourceError: could not load package ZServer: No module named interfaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating a clean virtualenv and then running your bootstrap and buildout using it. See: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Error-running-zeoserver-No-module-named-interface-td4634787.html

Comment: The link is broken.